# python how do I fix the label which is showing up multiple times in my subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have created a subplot and ploting a df in each, with labels. For some reason labels are showing up twice in each of the subplots. Any reason why this is happening?

```
labellist = ['A11','B11','C11','D11']
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(50,2)),columns=['A','B'])
    plt.plot(df,label= labellist[i])
    plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is occurring because you have two columns in your DataFrame. A different question that could be asked is which line should the label apply to? Or should there be 8 items in `labellist` instead?

Comment: yes actually good point! there should have been just one line for each of the subplot.i.e. just one column ! unfortunately my original problem is a lot more complicated so will have to edit the question again!

Comment: If you want just one label, you can use `plt.legend(labels=[labellist[i]])`. In that case `plt.plot(df)` can be called without a label.